# Unable to Configure Prometheus as a Datasource to Grafana secured by Oauth2 Proxy

Tags: kubernetes, oauth-2.0, devops, prometheus, grafana

How to Configure Prometheus as a Datasource to Grafana secured by Oauth2 Proxy. I have a Prometheus which is protected by an Oauth2 Proxy. I would want to configure this as a Datasource to Grafana, but I am unable to authenticate. Any Idea on how I can get this added.

Answer (score 0):

I resolve this task in docker-compose like this: just use internal Prometheus URL which does not use the Oauth2 Proxy - http://prometheus:9090 and my grafana connect to prometheus in the internal network. But others should auth in the Oauth2 Proxy.
I think this solution should to help you, cause in Kubernetes you can connect from pod to pod in the internal network if your the Ouath2 set like separate resource before prometheus.

If my solution doesn't help, you can follow the [thread](https://github.com/oauth2-proxy/oauth2-proxy/issues/1892). I think that you can try to find solution by set-cookie _oauth2_proxy.